# pywin32 Windows service doesn't want to send request status

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-services, pywin32

I have a python server made from `HTTPServer`. And I want to use this server as a Windows service:

This is how server looks:

```
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.wfile.write(bytes("Hi, guys.", "utf8"))


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.http_server = HTTPServer((host, port), Handler)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.http_server.serve_forever)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.http_server.shutdown()
        self.thread.join()

    @staticmethod
    def do_job():
        do_some_staff_here()
        time.sleep(1)
```

So, it's very simple. To create Windows service I use pywin32. Let's have a look at my code:

```
 class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "TestService"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.stop_requested = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.stop_requested = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        server = Server("", 8080)
        server.start()
        while not self.stop_requested:
            server.do_job()
        server.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

And there are some problems:

- In usual "service" mode (when I'm enabling it though desktop app), if I'm trying to open this page, it doesn't respond. In debug mode everything works fine.
- When I'm removing `self.send_response(200)`, service starts work fine in both modes.

So, what can be a reason of a such behavior?

**UPDATE**

I'm receiving next error, when I'm trying to execute `send_response()` :

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: im pretty sure that http.HTTPServer is not designed to be a production server... Ive seen a few questions like this recently, which makes me a bit nervous

Comment: :D i just need some sort of a light daemon on windows machine, so maybe that's a new trend

Comment: why not use one of the 100000000 million better solutions out there (ie apache or gunicorn) that are actually designed for this ?  I suspect any form of `HTTPServer.start()` will end up hanging and becoming unresponsive requiring restarting the service more frequently than you would like (yes even if you are just running locally) (I know this doesnt actually address your question...)

Comment: As I know(i can be wrong) , apache cant run server and infinite loop at the same time.

Comment: there is no infinite loop if you use apache (or gunicorn) ... you would stop the service by stopping apache or gunicorn

Comment: i'm not sure, that I understand, what u mean. What I want to have : server which accepts post requests, and once per day I need to send an email. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while writing a plugin for [QGIS](https://qgis.org) in python 3.7.
After some digging it tourned out that `send_response()` internally calls `sys.stderr.write` (in [log_message](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/970188c2d792133e2273924a987e0542659a676f/Lib/http/server.py#L577)) and `stderr` here is null. As I don`t know much about QGIS and python and plugins and all I can`t tell, why it`s like that. I solved this by simply overriding`log_message` in my plugin.